# Calculating the control energy of a non-optimal prespecified trajectory of an LTI

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

Given a linear time-invariant system:

$$ \dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t) $$

with 
initial state $ x(0)=x_0 $ and final state $ x(T)=x_T $.

Let's take the following matrix and controller:

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0.5 \\ 0.3 & -1 \end{bmatrix},    B=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

and let the initial state be $ x_0=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $  and the final state be $ x_T=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $.

How to find the control signal and the control energy for an arbitrarily chosen (not necessarily optimal) trajectory that connects the inital and final state $ \lambda(t) $?

A biological example would be to move an arm between two points, which can be any continuous movement.

Comment: Take any trajectory and record $u(t)$ then the energy is the 2-norm of it

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I also want to find the control signal/trajectory $ u(t) $

Comment: Since you are dealing with a continues system you can input any signal for the vast majority of the time interval. During the last fraction of the interval (which can be as arbitrarily small as you want) you could for example use [PMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen: Interesting approach, but won't that result in a state trajectory I am not able to specify? Let's take the arm movement as an example again and assume a trajectory of arm movement between two points was chosen by a person, i.e. the state trajectory is fixed and the resulting control signal needs to be calculated then. Will the approach you described work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can only find the control signal if the provided trajectory is feasible. Namely in order to satisfy the differential equation the terms which are not a function of $u(t)$ still need to lie inside the span of $B$. Since

$$
\dot{\lambda}(t) - A\,\lambda(t) = B\,u(t)
$$

so in order to solve for $u(t)$ the left hand side needs to be a multiple of $B$.

For example it can be shown that linear interpolation of the example system is not feasible

$$
\lambda(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \left(1 - \frac{t}{T}\right) + 
\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \frac{t}{T}
$$

$$
\dot{\lambda}(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{T}
$$

$$
\dot{\lambda}(t) - A\,\lambda(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - \frac{1}{T} \\
\frac{1}{T} - \frac{3}{10}
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
- \frac{3}{2} \\
\frac{13}{10}
\end{bmatrix} \frac{t}{T}
$$

namely the constant term only lies in the span of $B$ for one specific value of $T$ (namely $T=\frac{20}{13}$), however the time varying term never lies in the span of $B$ except at $t=0$. So on the interval $0<t<T$ the expression $\dot{\lambda}(t) - A\,\lambda(t)$ does not always lie in the span of $B$ and is therefore not feasible.

If $\lambda(t)$ is feasible you could use the [left inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) of $B$ if $B$ does not have a rank of $n$ (where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$) to find $u(t)$

$$
u(t) = \left(B^\top B\right)^{-1} B^\top \left(\dot{\lambda}(t) - A\,\lambda(t)\right).
$$

If $B$ does have a rank of $n$ then the normal inverse can be used and also any $\lambda(t)$ should be feasible, since $B$ would then span the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$

$$
u(t) = B^{-1} \left(\dot{\lambda}(t) - A\,\lambda(t)\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks Kwin. What I do not understand entirely is how you obtained the first equation?

Comment: @holistic $\lambda(t)$ represents a chosen trajectory of $x(t)$ by the user. So the first equation can be obtained by substituting $\lambda(t)$ for $x(t)$ into the dynamics $\dot{x}(t) = A\,x(t) + B\,u(t)$ and then bring $A\,\lambda(t)$ to the left hand side.

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks again